# Jenkins 2.0 workflow input step and GITHUB Authorization strategy

Tags: github, jenkins, oauth, jenkins-workflow

I am currently using Jenkins 2.0 with GITHUB Authorization strategy. I am creating a workflow in 2.0 in which one of the steps requires approval by a member or a group to proceed. I know about the input step and the submitter attribute can be used for achieving the same.

```
input message: "Do you want to proceed?", submitter: "cp"
```

The above works perfectly well for single users. How do I achieve the same for a group? In the context of GITHUB Authorization / security realm, what does a group mean in Jenkins and how does this work? I searched extensively but did not find any answers for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the answer finally. In the context of GITHUB Authorization / security realm, group represents teams in an organization. So, if you want members of a group to approve the input step, please pass the team name. Please note that the Org name and team name are separated by an asterisk!

```
input message: "Do you want to proceed", submitter: "GITHUBOrgName*TeamName"
```